# OnKeyListener() not working on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have applied OnKeyListener() on EditText & it's not working on Samsung Galaxy S3 but working on all other phones...
Don't know what i am doing wrong...

```
  et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
  et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value
            // with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                // this is for backspace
                Log.d("Button Event", "BackSpace Pressed");
                if (et.getSelectionStart() < length + 1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()..) and move all you logic to it's afterTextChanged(...) callback.

OnKeyListener() only gets invoked with events from the hardware keyboard, as stated on [View.OnKeyListener's description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)).

Comment: Abhishek is correct. OnKeyListener, OnGlobaTouchEvent etc etc all do not handle the softkeyboard touches. After researching for some time the only solutions I have found for key board event handling are to override methods of the object where the text is being entered. There is probably a reason for it but I think this is a serious fail on Android's part.